# Troubleshooting Microphone Integration for Python IDEs: Building a Laptop Assistant

Tags: python, speech-recognition, microphone

The microphone is not working for default python IDLE or any other IDE like VS Code, but my other applications are using the mic correctly like Recorder, Chrome, and YouTube. I'm making an assistant for my laptop.

I have tried different things. And it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

# Initialize the speech recognition engine
r = sr.Recognizer()

# Initialize the text-to-speech engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()

def listen():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said:", query)
        return query
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't catch that.")
        return ""
    except sr.RequestError:
        print("Sorry, I'm having trouble connecting to the speech recognition service.")
        return ""

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

# Main program loop
while True:
    speak("Hello, sir! I'm Jenny, your virtual assistant.")
    command = listen().lower()

    if command == "hello":
        speak("Hello, how can I help you?")

    elif command == "what's your name":
        speak("My name is Python Jarvis.")
```

Comment: Hi, Shahzad!  On StackOverflow, we can't answer questions with code that's in a linked image.  I have suggested an edit to your post that formats the code from the image as described in the site's guidelines here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557  The changes to your question won't be visible until you or another user approves the edit.

Comment: have you looked into [pyaudio](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/) or [sounddevice](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.6/) to enumerate your microphone input device?